# Delete older EBS Volume snapshots except few with certain tags using Python, Lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, amazon-web-services

I am learning Python and managed to accomplish the above. But my script doesn't seem optimal. Could someone help to take a review and suggest for betterment?

````
import boto3
from datetime import datetime,timedelta

REGION = "ap-southeast-1"
retention_days = 45
account_id = boto3.client('sts').get_caller_identity().get('Account')
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=REGION)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    now = datetime.now()
    outdated_snapID = []
    retain_snapID = []
    result = ec2.describe_snapshots(OwnerIds=[account_id])
    for snapshot in result['Snapshots']:
        # Remove timezone info from snapshot in order for comparison to work below
        snapshot_time = snapshot['StartTime'].replace(tzinfo=None)
        # Subtract snapshot time from now returns a timedelta 
        # Check if the timedelta is greater than retention days
        if (now - snapshot_time) > timedelta(retention_days):
            outdated_snapID.append(snapshot['SnapshotId'])
    retain_snap = ec2.describe_snapshots(OwnerIds=[account_id], Filters=[{'Name': 'tag:Retain', 'Values': ['True', 'true']}])
    for snap in retain_snap['Snapshots']:
        # Remove timezone info from snapshot in order for comparison to work below
        snapshot_time = snap['StartTime'].replace(tzinfo=None)
        if (now - snapshot_time) > timedelta(retention_days):
            retain_snapID.append(snap['SnapshotId'])
    # Remove retained snapshotID's from the outdated array
    for i in retain_snapID:
        outdated_snapID.remove(i)
    for x in outdated_snapID:
        delete_snapshot(x)

def delete_snapshot(snapshotID):
    try:
        ec2.delete_snapshot(SnapshotId=snapshotID)
    except Exception as ex:
        print("Something went wrong:", ex)
        pass
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a beginners' project, the code is well formulated, comments are short and to the point. I'll list out a few things which might help you, but are specific to your requirements.

---

### Environment variables

AWS populates an environment variable called `AWS_REGION` for its lambda execution environments. If your function is operating in the same region as the lambda is defined, you can leverage this instead of hardcoding the `REGION` and thereby making the function operable across regions without any changes.

Similarly, you can populate the `RETENTION_DAYS` (name constants using `CAPITAL_SNAKE_CASE`) via env vars.

### Client/service resource

I'm a huge supporter of the newer service resource API over the low-level client for boto3 operations. They are lazy loaded, have better support for pagination and more pythonic.

Check the documentation for [the same here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#service-resource).

### Duplicated task

You have 2 loops, iterating over all snapshots, and then over filtered snapshots (for retention). They both require the same computation of `snapshot_time` and checking with retention limit. Perhaps, a function to check if `snapshot` is worthy of retention, and proceed accordingly would be better?

### List vs set/tuple/dict

You know for sure that you only need to work with snapshot IDs, which are guaranteed to be unique. Using list for storage, and later calling `.remove` on list is not performant.

A better performance can be achieved if you use a set or tuple for storing the ids (since removal would be \$ O(1) \$ cost); however, if you plan to go with service resource, using a dictionary to map `id` to the snapshot resource would be my advice.